# discord.py команда !ping выдает одно и тоже значние

Tags: discord.py, ping

я собирался создать команду которая будет выводить данные о загруженности машины с ботом(в т.ч. автон.заряд, загруженность cpu пинг и оперативной памяти.) при прописаний команды все значения постоянно одинаковы и меняются только при следующем перезапуске бота.
код команды:

```
async def бот(ctx: commands.Context):
     embed=discord.Embed(title="загруженность бота", color=0x0400ff)
     embed.add_field(name="автономный заряд", value=f"{percentbat}%", inline=False)
     embed.add_field(name="CPU", value=f"{CPU}%", inline=False)
     embed.add_field(name="memory", value=f"{percentmem}%", inline=False)
     embed.add_field(name="ping", value=f"{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms", inline=False)
     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

переменные:

```
battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
percentbat = int(battery.percent)

CPU = psutil.cpu_percent()

mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
percentmem = int(mem.percent)
```

библиотеки которые я использую:
psutil
discord.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучай основы python, они всегда пригодятся :)

Когда ты создаешь переменную, ты присваиваешь ей значение, которое не изменяется.

Для того, чтобы исправить ошибку, изменяй содержимое переменной при каждом вызове команды.
Вот рабочий код:

```
async def бот(ctx: commands.Context):
     # Задаём переменные
     battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
     percentbat = int(battery.percent)
     CPU = psutil.cpu_percent()
     mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
     percentmem = int(mem.percent)

     # Создаём объект discord.Embed
     embed=discord.Embed(title="загруженность бота", color=0x0400ff)
     embed.add_field(name="автономный заряд", value=f"{percentbat}%", inline=False)
     embed.add_field(name="CPU", value=f"{CPU}%", inline=False)
     embed.add_field(name="memory", value=f"{percentmem}%", inline=False)
     embed.add_field(name="ping", value=f"{round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms", inline=False)

     # Отправляем наш embed
     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```